# Нужно сделать ссылку с запросом пользователя в кнопке и вывести это на QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, youtube, qlabel, qwebengineview

Не знаю как правильно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалась ссылка.

```py
...

users = str(input("Введите ваш запрос: "))
query = {'search_query': users}
browser = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results', params=query)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle("bows")
    btn = QPushButton()
    lable = QLabel(w)

    lable.setText('<a href="browser"> youtube </a>')
    lable.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из того что я понял, вы хотите загрузить Youtube в приложение,
если так, тогда попробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import ( 
    QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineProfile,
    QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineView,
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
      
        profile = QWebEngineProfile(self) 
        
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, self)
        self.webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.webview.load(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

        self.btn = QPushButton('Youtube.com')
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.setChecked(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_hide)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.webview, 1)
        lay.addStretch(0)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn, 0)
        
    def show_hide(self):
        print(f'{self.btn.isChecked()}') #
        if self.btn.isChecked():
            self.webview.show()
        else: 
            self.webview.hide()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]