# Почему не работает Youtube PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, youtube, qwebengineview

Пытаюсь понять, почему при таком коде работает любой сайт, кроме ютуба. 
Не подскажете, как можно сделать так, чтобы ютуб открывался?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(900, 600)

        self.view = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)

        self.view.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя у меня ваш пример работает, я вам предложу попробовать так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, \
    QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    webview = QWebEngineView()

    webpage = QWebEnginePage(webview)
    useragent = QWebEngineProfile(webview)    
    agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
    useragent.defaultProfile().setHttpUserAgent(agent)

    webpage.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture, False)   # <<<=====<

    webview.setPage(webpage)
    webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://youtu.be/Trdmf2pr_dw"))
    
    webview.resize(680, 500)
    webview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Через некоторое время проверю ваш способ)

Comment: Странно, но у меня и ваш пример не работает(

Comment: Причем в свой код я его еще не вставлял, запустил в отдельном файле только

Comment: @Bitchdragon вы запускаете с консоли\терминала\CMD? и что вы получаете ошибку или что?

Comment: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Простой py-файл, запускаю с кнопки run

Comment: Код, что закреплен в вопросе полностью работает с любыми другими сайтами, кроме ютуба

Comment: @Bitchdragon запускаете с консоли\терминала\CMD `python main.py`

Comment: С консоли, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Bitchdragon а это у вас работает ?
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1330673/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-qlabel/1330753#1330753

Comment: Работает! Дальше попробую разобраться, спасибо вам за помощь)

Comment: В моем коде все заработало!